# Using MatTooltip in MatIcon in Angular 8 causing problem

Tags: angular-material, tooltip, angular8

I try to show tooltip message in an input where a suffix icon appears. I think I did everywhing as the documentation says, but always got an error instead of what I want.

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for TooltipComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

Component.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatTooltipModule
]
```

Component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput placeholder="placeHolder" formControlName="myFormControl">
 <mat-icon matSuffix
   matTooltip="My tooltip comes here"
   matTooltipPosition="left">
    help_outline
 </mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ERROR Error: No component factory found for TooltipComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`
From this error i can tell you that you need to add TooltipComponent to entryComponetns in your module;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatTooltipModule
],
entryComponetns: [TooltipComponent]
```